# App engine endpoints auth with Google Identity Toolkit

Tags: java, android, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, google-identity-toolkit

I've successfully implemented user login in my android app with Google Identity Toolkit. I've also created an App Engine Endpoint to communicate from the Android app. Now I want to secure the endpoints with auth.

I know I can create a custom Authenticator for endpoint and do any kind of verification of the data in request header in there and get the job done.

But I don't know how to do the Gitkit verification there.
Basically

1. What data should I pass to reach endpoint calls from Android app?(token ID?)
2. What should I do in the custom Authenticator of endpoint to ensure the requests are valid?
3. I saw people suggesting to use Session or cookies. Will these work if I'm using the endpoint from Android app? If yes please give me some reference on how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Gitkit tokens are JWT format, so you validate them on server-side just as any other JWT token.

See example documentation on how to validate JWT here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth It's the same format.

I have also my own project to integrate it with Jersey server: 
https://github.com/dlazerka/gae-jersey-oauth2. It uses recommended `com.google.api-client` library to actually verify the token.